# Google App maker list view filtering

Tags: google-app-maker

We have tables in app maker that shows data in list view and it will add default features like sorting, paging. We want filters on top of each column in

that table, drop down control acts as filter that will list all the distinct values on its configured column. When I select a value in dropdown it should

filter the value from datasource and load in the list view.

If two filters or more filters is applied at the same time, the filters should act as AND condition that will bring values satisfied with all filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such type of table in App Maker at this time (but you can always file feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410))

Meanwhile you can put some effort and implement it on your own. You just need to add input widgets, layout them and bind to [filters(_equals, _in, _notIt, _startsWith...)](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Query):

```
@datasource.query.filters.FieldName._equals
```

There are some relevant apps with this functionality:

- [Project List](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/project-list/)
- [Project Tracker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/)

Comment: Thank you pavel, I will try