# Filter and Bind a Multiselect

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to implement a Many-to-Many relation between a class and its students in a form.

The form can be used to create or edit a class. Also students can be added to that class. To reduce the effort needed to enter students, I would like to add a multi-select that shows the entries from the `students`-table. But since the number of students is expected to be large, I would like to filter this multi-select.

I checked [this question on filtering lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001148/google-app-maker-list-view-filtering) and [the sample app "Project List](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/project-list/). I understand that the standard workflow with a table would be to bind the `value` of a search box to the `@datasources.STUDENTS.query.filters.email._contains` and set the tables `datasource` property to `STUDENTS`

But, as I understand it, a multi-select element's `value` property must be bound to `@datasource.item.students` and its `datasource` property must be `CLASS` in order for the auto-saving to work.

Hence I wonder whether it is possible to filter a multi-select element.

Comment: Have you considered creating a separate datasource for students and then setting your search box to that datasource and your multiselect options would be @datasources.StudentsFiltered.items? I use a similar process like this, just with a dropdown and whenever I select a new table row in a different datasource it re-filters my options in a dropdown based on my selected table row.

Comment: This would require a "Calculated Data Model", wouldn't it? I guess that could work. But isn't there a simpler way using the existing features?

Comment: Actually it could be just a regular datasource under Students model. I have several models with more than 6 datasources each, because I have the need to have my models filtered in different ways for different purposes, sometimes on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem, but I think I see a misunderstanding.

You said: "I understand that the standard workflow with a table would be to bind the value of a search box to the @datasources.STUDENTS.query.filters.email._contains"

You need to bind the OPTIONS (not value) to the datasource query, as it is the options that will draw its records from the @datasources.Students.query datasource.

You can then set the VALUE of the multi-select widget to @datasource.item.students (where you want selected values from the student query options to be saved).

You will also need to set the NAMES property (since the options are likely student records). Names will be the Student datasource projection of whatever string field you want to appear in the options list.